# Seeing what version of ruby is running on my mac "ruby -v"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very very new to ruby, I just read that my mac comes preinstalled with ruby and I can test it by typing ruby -v in the terminal but I get an error..

I was trying to follow this tutorial but with no luck on even the first command!
[Net Tuts tutorial on installing ruby](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac/)

"What you might be interested to know is that Ruby comes preinstalled on your Mac. Don’t believe me? Open the Terminal and type:"

```
ruby -v
```

response

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `v' for main:Object
from (irb):16
```

I have two questions, 
how can I see what version I have running and whats the best way to install ruby on mac?

Comment: Post the result of `which ruby`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **should not** use `ruby -v` while you are in the **irb**. You should type `ruby -v` on the **command line** not the interactive ruby shell

The best way to install and manage ruby in my opinion is rvm (though there are other choices like rbenv) so i would suggest you keep on following the steps of [the tutorial you have on your hands](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac/) (since that's the way it presents to install ruby)

Comment: If you really need to find out what version you are running in the interactive ruby shell then try `RUBY_VERSION` .

Comment: I think I'm missing something, i'm opening terminal.app and typing in there - current it now shows "ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]" --- Makis192, can you explain irb/commandline/interactive ruby shell?

Comment: You aren't missing anything. That's what should be printed out when you type ruby -v in the command line. Terminal.app is the terminal emulator/command line for MacOS. (command line = terminal = terminal.app)
(irb = interactive ruby shell)